# R Shiny: how to change stored data?

Tags: r, database, shiny, load, storage

I wrote a shiny app for sports betting which enables me to

1. run a model and pick a winner,
2. add additional variables if I decide to bet on a game and store this in a database, and
3. track my betting performance and adapt strategies using this information.

The app works fine so far, but has one major flaw: when I made the calculations and decide to bet on a game, I can simply add another row into a database by using a submit button. The problem is that I have two important columns for data analysis, which can only be added after the game. Thus, I would need to add or change information in a row I submitted before the game.

I built the data storage part of my app on [this](https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/) input of Dean Attali, so I use also the minimum example from this tutorial (thanks @Dean by the way). It is the basic app without storage, but I guess the important thing is to get back to already existing rows and change (or expand) them. Has anyone done something similar already or has an idea how this could be solved?

UPDATE: I found a solution for my problem here [enter link description here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28) (on the bottom - March 15th). I tried to implement it, but there is no reaction in the tables, since I obviously miss an important point. Does anyone has an idea how to make the table responding?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT@feature/editor')

saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
}

loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
    sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R",
            0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

# Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
formData <- reactive({
  data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
  data
})

# When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
observeEvent(input$submit, {
  saveData(formData())
})

# Show the previous responses
# (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
  input$submit
  loadData() %>%
    datatable(rownames = FALSE)
    })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("x1")

  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
  info <- input$x1_cell_edit
  i <- info$row
  j <- info$col + 1
  v <- info$value
  loadData[i, j] <<- DT:::coerceValue(v, loadData[i, j])
  replaceData(proxy, loadData, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
})     
  }
)
```

Comment: `responses` is a global variable that could be manipulated from anywhere. You could write a function like `saveData` that changes it and call that? I don't think I fully understand the problem here. Could you provide specific examples of what you're looking for?

Comment: using the example I posted above, how could you go back to a row already submitted and change a value within the app? let's say you inserted the wrong number of years using R? the most user-friendly way would be to click on the row and change a certain field. is that possible?

Comment: I know DataTables has a few live editing extensions, but none of that comes with `DT`. You could look into http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/ or google around for a live table editor

Comment: thanks for the hints. I found a solution for editing tables using `DT` (see update above). Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You've got some copy paste issues - `x1` is the name of the table from the example in that link

Answer (score 3):

I fixed up a few issues in the updated example that uses the [`DT` live editor](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28):

- Added `getDataValue` and `setDataValue` functions to read/manipulate single entries in the data frame
- Replaced the instances of `x1` (name of table from the example code on GitHub) with `responses`
- Added `simplify = FALSE` to the `sapply` so it returns a list instead of a vector. This is so data added to the table can be of different types. Vectors in R only have one type, so all the table data was being converted to strings, even `TRUE`/`FALSE`

```
# devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT@feature/editor')
library(shiny)
library(DT)

saveData <- function(data) {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
}

loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

getDataValue <- function(i, j) {
  stopifnot(exists("responses"))
  responses[i, j]
}

setDataValue <- function(i, j, value) {
  stopifnot(exists("responses"))
  responses[i, j] <<- value
  responses
}

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
    sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R",
                0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]], simplify = FALSE)
      data
    })

    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(input$submit)
      newData <- isolate(formData())
      saveData(newData)
      datatable(loadData(), rownames = FALSE)
    })

    proxy <- dataTableProxy("responses")

    observeEvent(input$responses_cell_edit, {
      info <- input$responses_cell_edit
      i <- info$row
      j <- info$col + 1
      v <- info$value

      newValue <- DT:::coerceValue(v, getDataValue(i, j))
      setDataValue(i, j, newValue)
      DT::replaceData(proxy, loadData(), resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks @greg for the update. `x1`was used by purpose, since also in the example it was done this way in order to create an proxy-variable, which then overwrites the actual value (that was my thought at least). anyway, I the corrected example from you and the behaviour is strange. when I submit several rows, it is always the same information regardless what I write in the text field or the other inputs. also, it is only possible to manipulate the first row, which then automatically changes all rows to the same value. could you reproduce this on your machine?

Comment: I've updated the post with a "working" example. There was something weird going on with `rbind`ing lists converted to data.frames. - not exactly sure why, but I'm looking into it later.

The updated example `rbind`s the added data without converting to a data.frame. Also, both the data saving and data rendering depended on the submit button being clicked. This was causing issues where the data was rendered before the data was saved, so I moved everything into renderDataTable. It's pretty bad, so I'd recommend making `responses` a reactive value.

Comment: thanks for the update. the `req(input$submit)`-function makes problems since it prevents that former entries are shown when the application is started. having only `input$submit` on the other hand leads so a situation, where a row with empty `name`and the values `FALSE`and `2`are added each time the app is started or updated. do you have any solution for that?
is it a problem to have the saving also included in the `renderDataTable`-function?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to the req(input$submit) issue ? If yes I would be very interested